# Нужен простой конвертер byte[] to Image WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть бд MSSQL в ней таблица в которой в поле Logo типа Image хранятся изображения формата jpeg(да, я знаю что так делать не есть хорошо но у меня такое тз). В шарпе работаю c LINQ. Крч мне нужно вывести картинку в элемент Image. Для этого нужен конвертер byte[] to Image, а всё что гуглил огромное и страшное. Если у вас есть какие либо конвертеры покидайте пожалуйста (преимущественно интересуют элегантные и простые решения, но можно покидать и простые народные). Буду очень благодарен.
Раньше на винформах юзал вот такое:

```
public static Image byteArrToImage(byte[] byteArr)
{
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArr);
Image pict = Image.FromStream(ms);
return pict
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну например так:

```
class FromBytesExtension : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is byte[] bytes) || LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
            return null;

        var image = new BitmapImage();
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            mem.Position = 0;
            image.BeginInit();
            image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.UriSource = null;
            image.StreamSource = mem;
            image.EndInit();
        }
        image.Freeze();
        return image;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;
}
```

Само преобразование взял c [EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9564425/6808809).

Пару пояснений:

- `value is byte[] bytes` - проверяем на тип входных данных, если не `byte[]`, то возвращаем `null`.
- `LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime` - Запрещаем дизайнеру Vusial Studio работать с этим классом, возвращая при этом `null`.

Также хочу заметить, что тут используется `MarkupExtension`, который в данном случае позволяет просто не делать нудный ресурс конвертера. Можете смело от него отказаться, но не забудьте добавить ресурс в XAML.

Использование:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Bytes, Converter={cw:FromBytes}}"/>
```